# Возникли трудности при обработке кнопок в Telegram боте

Tags: python, telebot

Есть телеграм бот,у него есть кнопки но при вводе команды /start выводяться кнопки при нажатии на одну из них выводиться курс текущей валюты но после нажатия на другую кнопку,остальные не выдают результат и приходиться перезапускать командой  /start

```
import config
import telebot
import requests
from telebot import types

bot = telebot.TeleBot(config.token)

# Декодировать json
response = requests.get(config.url).json()

@bot.message_handler(commands=['start', 'help'])
def send_welcome(message):
    markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True, row_width=3)
    itembtn1 = types.KeyboardButton('USD')
    itembtn2 = types.KeyboardButton('EUR')
    itembtn3 = types.KeyboardButton('RUR')
    itembtn4 = types.KeyboardButton('BTC')
    markup.add(itembtn1, itembtn2, itembtn3, itembtn4)
    msg = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 
                    "Привіт, обери валюту.", reply_markup=markup)
    bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, process_coin_step)

def process_coin_step(message):
    try:
       markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(selective=True)

       for coin in response:
           if (message.text == coin['ccy']):
              bot.send_message(message.chat.id, printCoin(coin['buy'], coin['sale']), 
                               reply_markup=markup, parse_mode="Markdown")

    except Exception as e:
       bot.reply_to(message, 'ooops!')

def printCoin(buy, sale):

    return " *Курс купівлі:* " + str(buy) + "\n *Курс продажу:* " + str(sale)

bot.enable_save_next_step_handlers(delay=2)

bot.load_next_step_handlers()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    bot.polling(none_stop=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

Вот код который работает так как вы хотели. Единственное что нужно в нем доработать - это получение курс валюты от какого-либо сервера

```
import telebot
import requests
from telebot import types

bot = telebot.TeleBot('BOT TOKEN HERE')


coins_list = ['USD', 'EUR', 'RUB', 'BTC']

@bot.message_handler(commands=['start', 'help'])
def send_welcome(message):
    markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True, row_width=3)
    markup.add(*coins_list)
    msg = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 
                    "Привіт, обери валюту.", reply_markup=markup)
    bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, process_coin_step)

def process_coin_step(message):
    try:
       markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(selective=True)
       coin_name = message.text
       course_of_coin = "25" # ToDo - получать данные из сервера какого-либо

       msg = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f"Вы выбрали валюту {coin_name}\n" + printCoin(course_of_coin, course_of_coin), reply_markup=markup)

       bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, process_coin_step)

    except Exception as e:
       bot.reply_to(message, 'ooops!')

def printCoin(buy, sale):
    return " *Курс купівлі:* " + str(buy) + "\n *Курс продажу:* " + str(sale)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    bot.infinity_polling()
```

Удачи!